# Combine 2 calculated fields into 1 calculated field in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I am trying to combine 2 calculated fields into 1 calculated field in tableau.

1st calculated field has this formula:

```
    SUM(IF [PRODUCT]="MA" THEN((IIF(YEAR([CARRIER_EFFECTIVE_DATE])=2018 AND 
YEAR([CALENDAR_DATE])<=2018, [TOTAL_COMMISSION],0))) END)/SUM(IF [PRODUCT]="MA" 
THEN((IIF(YEAR([CARRIER_EFFECTIVE_DATE])=2018 AND YEAR([CALENDAR_DATE])<=2018, 
[PAID_MEMBERS],0))) END)
```

2nd calculated field has this formula:

```
SUM(IF [PRODUCT]="MS"
THEN ((IIF(DATE([CARRIER_EFFECTIVE_DATE])=#2014-01-01# AND DATE([CALENDAR_DATE])
<=#2014-12-31#,[DATE_DEBIT_COMMISSION],0))) END)/ SUM(IF [PRODUCT]="MS"
THEN ((IIF (DATE([CARRIER_EFFECTIVE_DATE])>=#2014-01-01# AND 
DATE([CARRIER_EFFECTIVE_DATE])<=#2014-01-31#,[PAID_MEMBERS],0))) END)
```

I created these 2 calculations separately but when I am trying to combine together I get an error saying “Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate comparisons or results in ‘IF’ expressions"
Can someone please help in combining these 2 together?

Comment: Can you post your attempt at the combination? Then we can troubleshoot that.

Comment: IF [PRODUCT]="MA" THEN SUM(IF [PRODUCT]="MA" THEN((IIF(YEAR([CARRIER_EFFECTIVE_DATE])=2018 AND YEAR([CALENDAR_DATE])<=2018, [TOTAL_COMMISSION],0))) END)/SUM(IF [PRODUCT]="MA" THEN((IIF(YEAR([CARRIER_EFFECTIVE_DATE])=2018 AND YEAR([CALENDAR_DATE])<=2018, [PAID_MEMBERS],0))) END)
ELSE
SUM(IF [PRODUCT]="MS" THEN ((IIF(DATE([CARRIER_EFFECTIVE_DATE])=#2014-01-01# AND DATE([CALENDAR_DATE])<=#2014-12-31#,[DATE_DEBIT_COMMISSION],0))) END)/ SUM(IF [PRODUCT]="MS" THEN ((IIF (DATE([CARRIER_EFFECTIVE_DATE])>=#2014-01-01# AND DATE([CARRIER_EFFECTIVE_DATE])<=#2014-01-31#,[PAID_MEMBERS],0))) END)
END

Comment: I tried this but it says "Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate comparisons or results in ‘IF’ expressions"

Comment: I also tried this but it doesnt work

Comment: SUM(IF [PRODUCT]="MA" THEN
SUM(IF [PRODUCT]="MA" THEN((IIF(YEAR([CARRIER_EFFECTIVE_DATE])=2018 AND YEAR([CALENDAR_DATE])<=2018, [TOTAL_COMMISSION],0))) END)/SUM(IF [PRODUCT]="MA" THEN((IIF(YEAR([CARRIER_EFFECTIVE_DATE])=2018 AND YEAR([CALENDAR_DATE])<=2018, [PAID_MEMBERS],0))) END)
ELSE
SUM(IF [PRODUCT]="MS" THEN ((IIF(DATE([CARRIER_EFFECTIVE_DATE])=#2014-01-01# AND DATE([CALENDAR_DATE])<=#2014-12-31#,[DATE_DEBIT_COMMISSION],0))) END)/ SUM(IF [PRODUCT]="MS" THEN ((IIF (DATE([CARRIER_EFFECTIVE_DATE])>=#2014-01-01# AND DATE([CARRIER_EFFECTIVE_DATE])<=#2014-01-31#,[PAID_MEMBERS],0))) END)
END

Comment: I get the same error i.e. Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate comparisons or results in ‘IF’ expressions

Comment: I have 2 products, I am trying to calculate Cash per paid member. I am able to do that as individual fields but it is not working when I combine the 2 formulae

Comment: Can you try refactoring the two IF statements into a single IF? So if product = 'MA' AND Carrier date = 'x' AND Calendar Year = 2018 THEN commission. I have aa feeling that null values could be being returned by one of the if statements, which evaluates the condition to null

Answer (score 0):

In the combining IF statement, the [Product] field needs to be wrapped in ATTR() to make it an aggregation. Like this...

```
     IF ATTR([PRODUCT])="MA" ...
```

My test shows the calculation compiles as valid.

Here is the full calculated field as edited from your original.

```
IF ATTR([Product])="MA" 
THEN 
SUM(
    IF [Product]="MA" 
    THEN((IIF(YEAR([Carrier Effective Date])=2018 AND YEAR([Calendar Date])<=2018, [Total Commission],0))) 
    END)
/
SUM(
    IF [Product]="MA" 
    THEN((IIF(YEAR([Carrier Effective Date])=2018 AND YEAR([Calendar Date])<=2018, [Paid Members],0))) 
    END) 
ELSE 
SUM(
    IF [Product]="MS" 
    THEN ((IIF(DATE([Carrier Effective Date])=#2014-01-01# AND DATE([Calendar Date])<=#2014-12-31#,
        [Date Debit Commission],0))) 
    END)
/ 
SUM(
    IF [Product]="MS" 
    THEN ((IIF (DATE([Carrier Effective Date])>=#2014-01-01# AND DATE([Carrier Effective Date])<=#2014-01-31#,
        [Paid Members],0))) 
END) 
END
```

Comment: Any luck on this? If you figured it out on your own please add an answer and apply green check mark.